# is the dislike information still available on youtube's api?

Tags: youtube-api

since youtube updated thier guildlines on "dislikes" on the platform , see :  https://blog.youtube/news-and-events/update-to-youtube/

I wanted to ask if there is still a way to get the dislike amount on a random video using youtube's api , an example of a random video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThiCMd5kGbE&ab_channel=DigitalE

Comment: no they removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have access until Dec. 13th; after that only the user themselves with an authorized API call will be able to obtain that data for their videos only.

Comment: Supporting information: https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/134791097/update-to-youtube-dislike-counts?hl=en